# Too large top margin at the new page

Tags: margins

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,13pt,russian]{extreport}

\usepackage{extsizes}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}

\usepackage{vmargin}
\setmarginsrb{3cm}{2.5cm}{2cm}{2cm}{11pt}{1.8cm}{11pt}{10mm}

\begin{document}
\newpage
Hello
\end{document}
```

And here is the result:
[image]

The question is, why is the margin before text so large? Is there a way to reduce it?

Comment: Why don't you use `geometry` package?

Comment: Well I don't know. I'm newbie and just used the package I've read about.

Comment: OK, then better start using `geometry` for changing page layout. You can read the manual at `www.texdoc.net` or run `texdoc geometry` from command prompt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `geometry` instead of `vmargin`. But still, to answer why it happens, the macro `\setmarginsrb` has these arguments

```
\setmarginsrb{left margin}{top margin}{right margin}{bottom margin}{head height}{head sep}{foot height}{foot skip}
```

When you say

```
\setmarginsrb{3cm}{2.5cm}{2cm}{2cm}{11pt}{1.8cm}{11pt}{10mm}
```

You are specifying a top margin of `2.5cm` along with head height `11pt`, head sep of `1.8cm` so the first text line occurs at a distance of `2.5cm+11pt+1.8cm` from the top of the paper. Here is a demo of the same using `showframe` package.

[image]

Hope things are clear now. If you want to escape from these troubles, just use

```
\usepackage[left=3cm,right=2cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
```

Comment: `vmargin` has the big defect of abusing `\hoffset` and `\voffset`, but several other packages act under the assumption that these parameters keep their default value of 0pt.